# Unity Firebase storage errors not returning error

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, error-handling, firebase-storage

When loading file from Firebase storage using Unity:

If the file does not exist, the "ErrorRetryLimitExceeded" is the only error returned and it takes a couple of minutes. Why is the "ErrorObjectNotFound" not returned or other errors?

Here is the unity code:

```
public void Load (string folderName, Action<byte[]> loadResults = null)
{

    StorageFileName (folderName);
    ServicePointToggle (true);
    const long maxAllowedSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024;

    imaginary_ref.GetBytesAsync (maxAllowedSize).ContinueWith (task => {
        if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled) {
            Debug.Log (FirebaseStorageException (task.Exception));

        } else {
            Debug.Log("success");
        }
    });
}

public string FirebaseStorageException (Exception taskException)
{

    AggregateException ex = taskException as AggregateException;
    if (ex != null) {
        StorageException inner = ex.InnerExceptions [0] as StorageException;

        if (inner != null) {
            switch (inner.ErrorCode) {
            case StorageException.ErrorBucketNotFound:
                errorText = "Bucket Not Found";
                break; 
            case StorageException.ErrorCanceled:
                errorText = "Canceled";
                break; 
            case StorageException.ErrorInvalidChecksum:
                errorText = "Invalid Checksum";
                break; 
            case StorageException.ErrorNotAuthenticated:
                errorText = "Not Authenticated";
                break; 
            case StorageException.ErrorNotAuthorized:
                errorText = "Not Authorized";
                break; 
            case StorageException.ErrorObjectNotFound:
                errorText = "Object Not Found";
                break; 
            case StorageException.ErrorProjectNotFound:
                errorText = "Project Not Found";
                break; 
            case StorageException.ErrorQuotaExceeded:
                errorText = "Quota Exceeded";
                break; 
            case StorageException.ErrorRetryLimitExceeded:
                errorText = "Retry Exceeded";
                break; 
            case StorageException.ErrorUnknown:
                errorText = "Error Unknown";
                break; 
            }

        }

    }
    return errorText;
}
```

Comment: well... did you make sure that the path is existing? I am guessing that you already have a FireBaseStorage ref for this.

Comment: i am sure... if file exists, it's ok, it loads... but if not, it will take forever and will just return retry limit exceeded. what i wish to achieve is that it will return an error not found if file does not exist..